# Condition-in-scope as a rule for SequenceReplace

Tags: bugs, pattern-matching, scoping

**Bug persisting through 13.1.0 [CASE:4841653]**

---

From

```
Range@5 //SequenceReplace[_ :> Block[{}, Null /; False]]
Range@5 //SequenceReplace[_ :> Block[{}, Null] /; False]
Range@5 //SequenceReplace[_ /; False :> Block[{}, Null]]
```

we get:

```
{{1,2,3,4,5}}
{1,2,3,4,5}
{1,2,3,4,5}
```

The first line of output has an extra `{}`. As the `Condition` is `False`, we should expect it leave `Range@5` unchanged, so this is unexpected.

Same for `With` or `Module`, not only `Block`.

Comment: Why are you posting this here?

Comment: @lericr Make people know "this is unreliable". I feel it meaningful as I don't see WRI fix it since several versions.

Comment: Well, this is a question/answer forum, not a message board.

Comment: @lericr Questions are allowed to be answer by the questioner, and they can be "community wiki". I think they are designed to partially act as something like a message board. And no matter if this is a pure Q/A forum, it factually acts as the most developed Mathematica forum (even more than WRI's). So the qualification of a post may  originate from one's choice of pragmatism or dogmatism. And of course, factually depends on admins' decision and something democratic. e.g. this post can be closed by votes.